# Select everything between quotes over multiple lines

Tags: selection

Is there a way to select everything between quotes `"` `'` and `<backtick>` where the text contained between these quotes span multiple lines? `vi<quote>` will select everything in between the quotes but it only works on a single line. Basically, I want `vi<quote>` to work how `vi(` works which selects text spanning multiple lines and all

Use case for this is selecting a graphql query, which is wrapped around backticks, and spans multiple lines. Or selecting an entire python doc comment

If it's not predefined in vim, how can I go about writing a function for it?

Comment: I’m guessing you’re looking for something a bit more polished than `v/"<CR>hoNl`?

Comment: `v/"<CR>hoNl` would also work. How do I use it?

Comment: Type it in! ;). I’m sure someone will be along to write a proper answer soon, but if you can’t wait, take a look at https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects

Comment: `v/"<CR>hoNl` works pretty well (without the whole hoNl thing), but kinda breaks when it encounters an empty line. I checked out the link and that's what I tried to do first, but wasn't sure how to get to the quotes that a paragraph is wrapped in